# Missing function value after call

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for a class. The code calculates shipping charges based on data read in from a file. The issue I am having is in the calculation. The value passed from the volume function remains zero. I don't think I am passing it correctly. Also, need to not use globals - especially with the calculate function - use parameters was the last feedback I got from my prof.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream> 


using namespace std;  


void header(int lab_number, char lab_part)
{ 
    cout << "Kevin Schultz\n"; 
    cout << "Lab" << lab_number << lab_part << endl << endl; 
} 


double length, width, height, x, weight, total = 0, shipping_cost, volume;




int main () 
{ 
    double calculate(double length, double width, double height);
    double volume;
    double chargeAmount;
    double charge(ifstream & inFile, ofstream & prt);


    ifstream inFile; 
    ofstream prt("lab7new_out.txt"); 

    header(7, 'A'); 
    prt << "        S & S Global Services\n";
    prt << "    Shipping Cost Analysis Report\n\n"; 
    prt << "Length Width Height Weight Shipping\n"; 
    prt << "                             Cost\n\n"; 

    inFile.open("c:\\lab7\\pkg.txt"); 
        if (!inFile) 
        cout << "Error opening the file\n"; 

    inFile >> length; 
    inFile >> width; 
    inFile >> height; 
    inFile >> weight; 


    volume = calculate(length, width, height);      
    chargeAmount = charge(inFile, prt);



    prt << "------------------------------------" << endl;
    prt << "\nTotal cost: $" << total; 

    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 

} 

double calculate(double length, double width, double height)
        { 
            double volume; 
            volume = length * width * height; 
            return volume; 
        } 

double charge(ifstream & inFile, ofstream & prt) 
        {
            const double basic_charge = 12;
            const double Vsurcharge = 5;
            const double Dsurcharge = 4;
            const double Wsurcharge = 2;
            double netWeight = 0;

            while (!inFile.eof())  
            { 
                shipping_cost = basic_charge; 

                if (volume > 7)  
                    shipping_cost += Vsurcharge; 
                if (length > 3 || width > 3 || height > 3) 
                    shipping_cost += Dsurcharge; 
                if (weight > 50) 
                {
                    netWeight = weight - 50;
                    shipping_cost += netWeight * Wsurcharge; 
                }
                total += shipping_cost; 
                prt << setw(4) << right << setprecision(1) << length << setw(6) << right << setprecision(1) << width << setw(6) << right << setprecision(1) << height << setw(8) << right; 
                prt << weight << setw(5) << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << "$" << shipping_cost << endl; 

                inFile >> length; 
                inFile >> width; 
                inFile >> height; 
                inFile >> weight; 
            }
             return total;
        }
```

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: You don't actually call `calculate` at all.

Comment: @sftrabbit I tried adding:  volume = calculate(volume); before chargeAmount but it wont compile.

Comment: Your prof is right: get rid of the global variables. All of them. Don't proceed until you have removed them.

Comment: @KevinSchultz `calculate` takes three parameters: length, width and height, so you need to pass it the length, the width, and the height.

Comment: @molbdnilo When I move: double length, width, height, x, weight, total = 0, shipping_cost, volume;  into the main, I get a ton of errors about definition or declaration?

Comment: @KevinSchultz You really need to understand what you're doing rather than trying to hack it together and hoping that it works. Your definition of `calculate` takes *three* arguments: `length`, `width`, `height`. When you do `volume = calculate(volume);` you are passing only one argument (and the wrong one). Please get an introductory C++ book, read it carefully, and *understand*.

Comment: @sftrabbit - I fixed that but didn't edit the original code. The part I dont get is doing away with the global variables while maintaining the prototypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your professor said, please don't use global variables. In your code you have different variables `volume` and I doubt that you know when you are accessing which of the variables. Let's do a walk through your code:

```
 double volume;    // global variable, never written, read in function charge

 int main() {
    ...
    double volume; // local variable, only visible in function main, but never used
    ...
 }

 double calculate(double length, double width, double height) {
    double volume; // local variable, only visible in calculate
    volume = ...;
    return volume;
 }

 double charge(ifstream & inFile, ofstream & prt) {
    ...
    if(volume > 7) // no local variable volume defined, so using global variable volume
    ...
 }
```

Also, you declare a function calculate, but you never call it.

Please consider enabling as much compiler warnings as possible. It will help you find the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. The problemn is that you need to declare your function prototype before calling it, but if you put your main function to the bottom of your .c file you don't need to decalre the prototype function, hope it's clear

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream> 


using namespace std;  


void header(int lab_number, char lab_part)
{ 
    cout << "Kevin Schultz\n"; 
    cout << "Lab" << lab_number << lab_part << endl << endl; 
} 


double length, width, height, x, weight, total = 0, shipping_cost, volume;

double calculate(double length, double width, double height)
{ 
    double volume; 
    volume = length * width * height; 
    return volume; 
} 

double charge(ifstream & inFile, ofstream & prt) 
{
            const double basic_charge = 12;
            const double Vsurcharge = 5;
            const double Dsurcharge = 4;
            const double Wsurcharge = 2;
            double netWeight = 0;

            while (!inFile.eof())  
            { 
                shipping_cost = basic_charge; 

                if (volume > 7)  
                    shipping_cost += Vsurcharge; 
                if (length > 3 || width > 3 || height > 3) 
                    shipping_cost += Dsurcharge; 
                if (weight > 50) 
                {
                    netWeight = weight - 50;
                    shipping_cost += netWeight * Wsurcharge; 
                }
                total += shipping_cost; 
                prt << setw(4) << right << setprecision(1) << length << setw(6) << right << setprecision(1) << width << setw(6) << right << setprecision(1) << height << setw(8) << right; 
                prt << weight << setw(5) << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << "$" << shipping_cost << endl; 

                inFile >> length; 
                inFile >> width; 
                inFile >> height; 
                inFile >> weight; 
            }
     return total;
}

int main () 
{ 

    double volume = calculate(length, width, height);
    double chargeAmount;


    ifstream inFile; 
    ofstream prt("lab7new_out.txt"); 

    header(7, 'A'); 
    prt << "        S & S Global Services\n";
    prt << "    Shipping Cost Analysis Report\n\n"; 
    prt << "Length Width Height Weight Shipping\n"; 
    prt << "                             Cost\n\n"; 

    inFile.open("c:\\lab7\\pkg.txt"); 
        if (!inFile) 
        cout << "Error opening the file\n"; 

    inFile >> length; 
    inFile >> width; 
    inFile >> height; 
    inFile >> weight; 

    chargeAmount = charge(inFile, prt);


    prt << "------------------------------------" << endl;
    prt << "\nTotal cost: $" << total; 

    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: The assignment requires me to use prototypes.

Comment: put your prototype after the using command like this:`void header(int lab_number, char lab_part);
double calculate(double length, double width, double height);
double charge(ifstream & inFile, ofstream & prt);`